# Running Code during Dialog initialization, after GUI is drawn

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2017, mfc, windows-10

I'm writing an application that communicates and initializes instruments (via COM ports) during the initialization phase of a Dialog (using MFC, on Windows 10).

The instrument initialization is presently taking between 4 seconds and 10 seconds.  So the GUI won't appear until the initialization is finished.

I want to know how to perform the drawing of the GUI, then call the instrument initialization function.

Here's a code fragment:

```
BOOL MyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
  //...
  // code to initialize dialog widgets
  //...  

  Initialize_Intruments();
  return false;
}
```

From the [Microsoft Documentation of the `CDialog::OnInitDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=msvc-160#oninitdialog) method:

> **Remarks**
>
> Windows sends the WM_INITDIALOG message to the dialog box during the Create, CreateIndirect, or DoModal calls, **which occur immediately before the dialog box is displayed**. {emphasis mine}

I want to perform functionality, after the dialog box is displayed, during initialization of the dialog.
How to do this using C++, MFC, Visual Studio (2017) and Windows 10?

*Notes:*

1. The application is a single dialog that runs test procedures.
2. A splash screen is another technique under consideration.

Comment: Not sure, but handling [`CWnd::OnShowWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#onshowwindow) might be appropriate.

Comment: You cannot run code during dialog initialization yet no sooner than after dialog initialization has finished. There's still hope, though, using this new-fangled thing called multithreading.. It's all the rage these days.

Comment: Besides threads and depending on context, you could also `SetTimer` at the end of InitDialog, or `PostMessage` a custom message to be handled after the dialog opened.

Comment: The `SetTimer` method suggested in the comment above is the simplest method IMO, but then your user won't be able do to any interaction for several seconds. I'd make a "splash dialog" that just displays "Please wait..." using the `SetTimer` method, do the initialisation and then display the actual dialog.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an API that is called after the GUI is drawn.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews non, there is no such thing.

Comment: Why should there be a callback for this particular scenario? The system provides something a lot more flexible: Low-priority messages. They are the system's way to notify an application that nothing important is happening anymore. `WM_TIMER` messages are such low-priority messages. Though that's not going to make for a user-friendly UI. If you want to show a usable UI while doing background work, either one has to live on a separate thread. C++20 coroutines are the most convenient way to do that.

Comment: There may be uses for initialization after the dialog is drawn.  Presently the order is 1) Application Initialization, then 2) Drawing of the Dialog.  In my situation, I would like to have the order: 1) Pre-drawing initialization, 2) drawing of the dialog, then 3) Initialization after drawing.  Creating and managing threads adds more complexity to the application.  In my application, the Instrument Initialization thread would need to communicate the initialization status (including details) to the Dialog Box thread (possible, yes and more complicated).

Comment: I would try capturing the `WM_PAINT `message (`OnPaint()`), for the dialog. Put your code after calling the base-class `CDialog::OnPaint()` (add a boolean member variable and check/set it, to make sure that it is run only once).

Comment: A timer allows you to do what you are asking for. Just `SetTimer` in your `OnInitDialog`, and `KillTimer` it on first hit. It'll fire the first time you call a message retrieval function when there aren't any higher priority messages left to dispatch. That's precisely after the first `WM_PAINT` message was handled.